# Flutter inherit all props from parent widget

Tags: flutter

I want to make custom button on flutter. here is some code:

```
// class LoadingButton.dart

MaterialButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(Spacing().value(2)),
  textColor: Colors.white,
  disabledColor: Colors.grey[100],
  ...props
);
```

How can I add props dynamically without stating constructor one by one?

I've tried using `...props` but it wont add to the props.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in Dart. Only copy-pasting all properties will work.

Comment: so I can't put any default props MaterialButton has without initialize it one by one?

Comment: Indeed. You have to specifically write all of these properties

Comment: Ah.. this is real sad!